# Problema al insertar dependencia de Lombok en Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, lombok

Estoy usando Android Studio y mi versión de Gradle es la 7.1.1
Cuando inserto la dependencia de Lombok en mi buil.gradle de esta manera:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

luego de darle a Sync Project me muestra lo siguiente en la consola de Build:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

Alguien sabe a qué se debe esto?

Comment: En que build.gradle agregaste este en el del proyecto o el que se encuentra dentro de /app?

Comment: el mensaje que ves es un warning, no un error.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo solucioné eligiendo en Gradle Settings la version de IntelliJ IDEA
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las opciones de Gradle tenia por defecto apuntando a Gradle (default) y me lanzaba el error, al cambiarlo a IntelliJ dejó de marcarme el error.

Comment: Hola usuario nuevo, antes que todo tenga en cuenta que respuestas/preguntas que solo muestren una imagen o una respuesta sin explicación no suelen ser bien aceptadas, edite su respuesta y explique porqué funciona esa solución o porqué es útil, _es una recomendación_.